# Korach's logic regarding the link between birth order and jobs

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, levites-leviyim, parshat-korach

I'm confused with [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.16.1?lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.16.1.4&lang2=he&w2=all&lang3=he)'s view on Korach's claims:

> "אָמַר קֹרַח, אַחֵי אַבָּא אַרְבָּעָה הָיוּ,
>   עַמְרָם הַבְּכוֹר נָטְלוּ שְׁנֵי בָנָיו גְּדֻלָּה ...
>   מִי רָאוּי לִטֹּל אֶת הַשְּׁנִיָּה?
>   לֹא אֲנִי שֶׁאֲנִי בֶּן יִצְהָר, שֶׁהוּא שֵׁנִי לְעַמְרָם.

Through the whole Torah, we don't see that G-d follows that rule strictly: Adam's sons - Shes was the third, Noah's 3 sons - Shem was the second, Yakov was the second, Reuben got nothing out of his בכורה, and Levi got it all being the third, Moses got Kejunah initially being the second etc.

Why would Korach suddenly assume that the privileges are distributed according to the order of birth?

Comment: Re: Question 1: Korach was not necessarily arguing that a firstborn should receive greatness. He wasn't even arguing that the firstborn should**n't** receive greatness (which would make more sense, as he was the son of Levi's _second_ son). He was arguing that the two high positions should be divided between the sons of Levi, instead of between the sons of Amram (firstborn of Levi). Re: Question 2: So, who do you think should have done what to prevent "the whole mess and the death of close to 15 thousand Jews"?

Comment: Re Moshe originally being the Kohen - Aharon wasn’t the oldest either; Miriam was older than either of them.

Comment: VTC as too broad; your two questions should be split apart. I think they’re very good questions individually, but they don’t seem to have much to do with each other.

Comment: @DonielF Done!!

Comment: I voted to reopen, but I'm leaving my -1. Basically all your examples are exceptions: Adam's two first sons were excluded because one was killed and the other was the killer. Yaakov bought the Bechorah off Eisav. Reuvain (and Shimon and Levi) were excluded in Birchos Yaakov due to actions they did in their lifetimes. Shevet Levi earned their position during the Golden Calf. The last paragraph alone isn't inherently a bad question, but trying to bolster it through these examples severely detracts from it.